# How to use WebRTC in Android Kitkat?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I want to use WebRTC in WebView in Kitkat. but the webview does not supported.

1. Can i upgrade the `Chrome SDK` in Android.
2. Is there any method so that `kitkat` support the `WebRTC`

   ```
   WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
       settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
       webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           @Override
           public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
               Log.d("TAG", "onPermissionRequest");
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                   request.grant(request.getResources());
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you can try:

1. Update `Android System Webview` from Play Store.
2. update Chrome for Android.

Comment: Android System webview can't be updated in Kitkat. Also update chrome update the installed chrome browser.

Comment: Android System Webview update is start supported from android L. Before that Android System Webview is using chromium v30 and min version required is v36 for display.